# Run EXE from RDP Window (RDP Window is linked to Weblink)

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

A Weblink login has list of IPs connecting to remote desktop

I am able to click particular ip using “ie.document”

But that links open another window of Remote Desktop (Which is Server) of that IP

Directly I am not able to take remote connection due to security reason.

There is one EXE in C drive of Server PC(Remote Desktop Pc).

How can I run that EXE , Login and extract required File using VBA?

I have done few coding till IP List

I have tried APPACTIVATE , Not able to Run that EXE, Please Suggest

```
   USR = Workbooks(MP).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    PWD = Workbooks(MP).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value

    Dim ie As Object


    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "http://web.xyz.com/frmLoginACMO.aspx"
    While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_MainContent_txtusername").Value = (USR)
    ie.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_MainContent_txtpassword").Value = (PWD)
    ie.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_MainContent_imgbtnLogin").Click

    AppActivate "10.24.187.203@op_BoUSer-WindowsRDP"
```

Comment: Please take time to feedback on prior answers given and accept answers that have worked. You have left a string of questions which have no accepts nor clarifications given when requested.

Comment: Also, be very clear about whether a remote connection is required and is not permitted as that becomes an issue which way well involve your IT dept.